# Guice assisted injection deeper down the dependency hierarchy

Tags: java, guice

I want to conduct a chain of processing elements and wire them together via Guice. Let's assume the following path:

- `interface A` implemented by `class AImpl` needs some input
- `interface B` implemented by `class BImpl` needs `A`
- `interface C` implemented by `class CImpl` needs `B`
- `interface D` implemented by `class DImpl` needs `C`

The dependency of A can only be resolved at runtime and not at configuration time. The usual approach would be to use Assisted Injection in this case to create a factory, that takes the missing instances as parameters, just like this:

```
public interface AFactory {
    public A createA(String input);
}
```

But what I actually want is something like this:

```
public interface DFactory {
    public D createD(String inputForA);
}
```

I don't want to manually pass `AImpl`-specific dependencies through the whole hierarchy.
Is it possible to achieve this with Guice? If not, what's the best way to circumvent this problem elegantly while still retaining benefits of injection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Cheating way:** Stick `input` in a static variable or singleton `ThreadLocal`. Set it before your pipeline starts and clear it after it ends. Bind everything else through DI.

**Fancy way:** In `A`, refer to a `@PipelineInput String inputString` but don't bind it in your main injector. Otherwise, bind dependencies as you normally would, including referring to `@PipelineInput` in other pipeline-related classes. When you do need a `D`, get it from your implementation of a `DFactory`, which I'm calling `PipelineRunner`.

```
public class PipelineRunner {
  @Inject Injector injector; // rarely a good idea, but necessary here

  public D createD(final String inputForA) {
    Module module = new AbstractModule() {
      @Override public void configure() {
        bindConstant(inputForA).annotatedWith(PipelineInput.class);
      }
    };
    return injector.createChildInjector(new PipelineModule(), module)
        .getInstance(D.class);
  }
}
```

Naturally, binding attempts for `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` will fail outside of `PipelineRunner` for lack of a `@PipelineInput String`--you'll get a `CreationException` when you create the injector with those unsatisfied dependencies, as you discovered--but those pipeline-based dependencies should be easy to separate into a Module that you install into the child injector.

If this feels too hacky, remember that PrivateModules are also "[implemented using parent injectors](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html)", and that the whole point of dependency injection is to make a dependency like `inputForA` available to the whole object graph in a decoupled way.

Comment: I have to recall my approval, beacuse of this: "injection attempts for A, B, C, and D will fail outside of PipelineRunner for lack of a @PipelineInput String" This doesn't work, because Guice verifies Injectors at configuration time and fail as soon as it detects an unsatisfied binding, which is why you cannot create an almost complete Injector, that will be completed by its child. Private Modules overcome this by using a special binder.

Comment: My mistake; you do have to bind A, B, C, and D adjacent to the constant. Trivial to fix, though. Answer updated.

Comment: Okay, so I have to bind everything that's related to the pipeline exclusively inside the child injector and the parent injector only knows about the factory ("PipelineRunner").

Comment: That's right. The child injector classes can refer to things bound in the parent injector, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I see three options. They depend on how often you change the `input` for `A` .

1) Bind `input` as a constant in your module. This works only, if you know that value before you create the `Injector` and never want to change the value. See [`bindConstant`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#bindConstant%28%29)

2) Use a private submodule which binds either `A` or the value for `input` inside that module. Basically you can have two or three instance graphs with different value. See [newPrivateBinder](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#newPrivateBinder%28%29).

3) Use  a `Scope` ala `RequestScope`, `SessionScope`, ... This way you can change the input often but **you** must enter/leave the scope at some point to be defined. See [Custom Scopes](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes) for an example.

Comment: 1) is too late and 2) is just a special case of 1). I also thought about scopes, but that's so much boilerplate for such a small problem that I'd rather leave out DI altogether for elegancy's sake :-/