# How to configure providers with custom parameters?

Tags: java, guice

My class depends on some services which needs to take few parameters and then make network call, currently I am passing those parameters and then creating those services via a factory injected into my class. I need to inject those services as a dependency instead, I know that I can create providers for them but in most of the examples I see that the providers are often bound to the fixed values like `serveraddres` etc. but I need to give then values during run time.

Below is my example code:

```
public SomeClass {
   private final SomeFactory someFactory;

   @Inject
   SomeClass(SomeFactory factory) {
      someFactory = factory;
   }

   public Foo getFoo(String fooId) {
      FooService fooService = someFactory.getFooService(fooId);
      return fooService.getFoo();
   }

}
```

What I need to do is:

```
public SomeClass {
   private final FooService fooService;

   @Inject
   SomeClass(FooService fooService) {
      this.fooService = fooService;
   }

   public Foo getFoo(String fooId) {
      return fooService.getFoo();
   }

}
```

**Update 1**

Making the use case more clear:

```
  @Provides
  @RequestScoped
  public SomeService provideSomeService(Dep1 dep1, String code) throws IOException {
    return new SomeService.Builder()
        .withApplicationName("Foo")
        .setCode(code)  
        .build();
  }
```

Here, `code` can be `null` by default and when needed I can give some value in it.

Can I somehow pass arguments to the provider before its created?

Comment: you can do this only if `code` can be injected: statically (because of some configuration), or through some provider (in your case, because `code` is constant but related to the scope of the session)

Comment: @JérémieB if we are on the same page then we can't do anything with dynamic values in Guice, in that case I need to restructure my app, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a binding for your value (here, `code` is a String without a binding annotation), then your Update 1 is exactly what the code would look like.

In practice, there are a few differences:

- Constants like `int` and `String` values are generally annotated with a binding annotation, either `@Named` or a custom annotation.
- If you need to inject a value into an object graph after Guice initialization, but have a deep enough object graph that dependency injection is still a good idea, you can create a [child injector](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#createChildInjector-java.lang.Iterable-). This way you can make a `@Named("code") String` accessible within one action or object, but not across your entire Guice application.
- If your value for `code` is dynamic enough that it can't be provided through Guice as a key of its own, then you'll have to pass it in using a factory of some sort. For a Builder-based object, I'd say that your `SomeFactory` implementation is the best that I would come up with in your case.

If you don't need to use a Builder, and can let Guice create the object based on your fields or constructor parameters, you can code-generate a Factory.

- Guice can generate a factory for you through FactoryModuleBuilder, in a feature known as ["assisted injection"](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject).
- Google's other tool, [AutoFactory](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/factory), will code-generate a factory implementation that works in both Guice and Dagger. (It's bundled as "Auto", which includes a model object generator called AutoValue that also generates annotation implementations.)

I put a small demonstration of a child injector and assisted injection in [my other SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362711/how-can-i-wire-up-n-chains-of-nodes-in-guice-like-filters/32364325#32364325).

Comment: By needed I mean that run time I can change value of code, but I think it's not a good idea. I think guice is build or good only for static dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here is to parameterize the module and pass the parameter through to a provider that you create at runtime:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  private final String code;

  public MyModule(String code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  @Override public void configure() {
    Provider<Dep1> depProvider = getProvider(Dep1.class);
    bind(SomeService.class)
        .toProvider(() -> new SomeService.Builder()
            .withApplicationName("Foo")
            .withDep(depProvider.get())
            .setCode(code)  
            .build())
        .in(RequestScoped.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is being set during module initialization hence we can't reset code during run time.

Comment: well, Strings are immutable anyway, so they can't be changed at run time. Perhaps pass in an `AtomicReference<String>` and depend on that, changing it at run time? I would say this is a big anti-pattern though and not how Guice should be used. Consider having the thing which depends on the changing string call some other service to get its current value.

Comment: Suppose there is a service in the dependency graph which can have different behavior on the basis of some parameter like http request then can you do that with guice?

Comment: no. The best thing there would be to inject a factory and pass that the parameter.

Comment: can you put up some example?