# Guice 3 - Automatically building object graph when using assisted inject

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Im interested what is the proper manner to construct object with dependencies which themselves have @Assisted params. An example will better illustrate:

Ordinarilly with dependencies that do not have `@Assisted` params you can simply have a complex heirarchy of objects which all have their dependencies and these get injected no problem, I can just get an instance of an object and all its dependencies will be generated and injected without me having to do anything.

But if I wanted to change it so some of the dependencies in the object hierarchy have `@Assisted` params then I have to create those instances myself using a factory ie:

```
public SomeConcreteService(@Assisted String string) {
    this.string = string;
}

MyFactory myFactory = injector.getInstance(MyFactory .class);
SomeService myService = factory.getMyService("some string");
```

This would cause problems for the clean instantiation of the objects because I would have to manually create those instances. and pass them into the required object, which essentially renders the DI for that object redundant I think???? ie I would then need to use the `new` keyword and pass in all dependencies manually...

```
new MyComplexObject(myService, myOtherService)
```

How do I make it so that I don't have to manually build the object graph if one or more of the dependencies uses `@Assisted` parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you need to ask yourself is, "why am I making this `@Assisted`, and who is going to create these objects?"

If you use the key to get an instance you need, then what you have is fine:

```
public class YourInjectableClass {
  @Inject private MyFactory factory;

  public void doStuff(String key) {
    // You have a key, and your factory, so you can create the instance yourself.
    SomeService service = factory.getMyService(key);
    // [...]
  }
}
```

But if you use the key to get an instance create an instance to create an instance to get what you need, then that seems problematic. That might be a better problem for [child injectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316719/guice-assisted-injection-deeper-down-the-dependency-hierarchy/16331859#16331859):

```
public class YourInjectableClass {
  @Inject private Injector injector;
  public void doStuff(String key) {
    // You need an OuterObject. So rather than calling
    // new OuterObject(new InnerObject(factory.getMyService(key))), do:
    OuterObject outerObject =
        injector.createChildInjector(new OuterObjectModule(key))
        .getInstance(OuterObject.class);
    // [...]
  }
}
```

Because your value is needed throughout the dependency tree, you can treat it as an injected dependency. This can be a little more confusing, but saves you from letting your dependencies care about instantiation details all the way down the line.

Alternatively, you can create a manual OuterObjectFactory facade which does manually call `new`. This may be a better solution for legacy code, but can help to follow the Single Responsibility Principle by ensuring that one class is responsible for abstracting away instantiation details.

---

N.B. I'm assuming that `SomeConcreteService` takes other dependencies that the object graph can provide. If not, then there's no reason to use injection at all: Give SomeConcreteService a public constructor and call `new SomeConcreteService("your value here")` where needed. Though Guice takes some pains to abstract away the use of `new`, it is also unnecessary to create data objects or dependency-light objects like `HashMap` or `Date`.

Comment: I actually have no real world scenario for this I was just thinking about it. But however even if `SomeConcreteService` required no other dependencies it might still be good to manage it with Guice if it can, for instance, be switched out for another service; just thinking.

Comment: With respect to your answer I think that most of the time your 1st example would suffice. The main change would be: inject the factory and have some essentially `init()` method to initilise the dependency (I was assuming it would be used more than once throughout the class), or if just being used once then the `doStuff()` method would suffice. So I would need to add extra logic to pass in the key as you say which is understandable. Your 2nd example however I don't think I fully understand yet I'll spend some time looking in to it :)