# Google Guice - Custom scope and assisted injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, code-injection

using Google Guice, I'd like to create a class in runtime (to be more specific: a user class) and pass different components to the constructor (e.g. TransactionComponent, AchievementComponent; actually Guice should do that).

That's easily done using a Provider. Nevertheless, the components eventually need to know about each other. Additionally, I want them to load data based on the user id.

I guess that I would need some kind of custom scope in order to achieve that every component gets created only once for a specific user.. Not sure how to do this though.

Every components requires the user ID. I might be able to create the components in the user class using a custom factory and Assisted Injection.. but I'm not sure how component A could know of component B. Is it okay to use AssistedInject for passing a required component B to component A? But then, I wouldn't make use of a custom scope.. Any suggestion? :)

Cheers,
Guice noob

Comment: You're probably looking for something like _child injectors_, like in [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16316719/1426891). Is that related to your problem?

Comment: I once read that I should inject only once at the root object.. would that be an exception?

Comment: By "inject only once at the root object", do you mean "use an Injector directly"? I'd say so: It's definitely preferable for normal dependencies to inject `Foo` or `Provider<Foo>` rather than carrying around an Injector and using `getInstance`, but Guice doesn't provide any way to create a child injector other than to use the Injector reference itself (which, [according to class-level Javadoc here](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html), is injectable). In contrast, the newer framework Dagger allows for injecting a Builder that you define.

Comment: Closing for now because this seems to be a similar request. Very willing to reopen if you or anybody else sees this as a different question.